# The easiest way to create a web-site with complex thing in it

Tags: html, database-design, server, web-development-server

My friend mechanic is asking me to create a web-site for him. All he needs is a search. Three tabs (model, year, make), then the web-page shows all the cars that satisfy the conditions. And if we click on the car, it will show more information about it. Also this man is not very in hi-tech, so there should be a simple form to add a car. (Screenshot is attached).

So, I know how to do it in JavaScript and MySQL (then CSS + HTML). But is there some easier and faster way to do it? I know there are templates, but they only include some simple stuff, like info. Here is a screenshot how I would like it to look. [How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5dz1.png)

Comment: Find an experienced full stack developer to do it for you.  The site in your screenshot could be done in a few hours to days, but the implementation depends on a wide variety of technologies that would take longer to explain than to do.  SO isn't the place for such broad questions and answers.

Comment: None of us have money for full stack developer. I was more thinking that there are site templates with ability to create primitive web-site, what about some templates or instruments for more complicated web-sites.

Answer (score 0):

So, easiest thing to do was to create a web-site on wix.com then combine with caspio.net . Created a required thing in couple hours.